# VML to HTML or image

Tags: vml

I have to convert the shapes in VML present in xml(docx file) to be display either in html or as image in html..can you help me..Thanks in advance..provide me with code..

Answer (score 0):

1. Display your image in whatever viewer you have available (Office, Internet Explorer)
2. Take a screenshot and crop the interesting part to an image, let's say `interest.jpg`
3. Use `<img src="interest.jpg" alt="What an interesting image!" />`